# MobileFirst 7.1 - Manage Cordova

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

With MFP 7.1 can I replace cordova ios 3.7 or android 3.6.4 with an even newer or older ones? Since MFP is now a Cordova Plugin, I should just take care about the plugin compliance between MFP and Cordova itself... Shouldn't I?
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the tutorial for using Cordova in MobileFirst, currently you cannot.

Make sure to thoroughly read it.
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/